# Add line to particular column in table?

Tags: tables

I want to make an [table like this](http://imageshack.com/a/img24/1628/ti1v.png)

Here is my LaTeX code:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of all discussed Classifiers} \begin{tabular}{|>
{\raggedright}p{1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|}
\hline

 3. & Template Matching (TM) & Computed very simple and Need matching the template over 
 the image & Rotation and Scalling variant \tabularnewline
  & & Easy change if there are a new classes of signs &  \tabularnewline
 \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \label{Classifiers_Com}
  \end{table}
```

I want to make the 3rd columm has a line to separate those sentences

**"Computed very simple and Need matching the template over the image**"
and
 **"Easy change if there are a new classes of signs"**

How to do it??

Comment: Your example isn't a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) because it is even *too* minimal and not working yet.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of all discussed Classifiers} 
\begin{tabular}{|>
{\raggedright}p{1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|}
\hline

 3. & Template Matching (TM) & 
 \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
 \begin{itemize}[label= \textbf{--},leftmargin=*,itemsep=0ex]
 \item Computed very simple and Need matching the template over
 the image 
 \item Easy change if there are a new classes of signs
 \end{itemize}
 \end{minipage}
 & Rotation and Scalling variant \tabularnewline

 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering
\caption{Comparison of all discussed Classifiers}
\begin{tabular}{|>
{\raggedright}p{1cm}|>{\raggedright}p{3cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|}
\hline

 3. & Template Matching (TM) & Computed very simple and Need matching the template over
 the image & Rotation and Scalling variant \tabularnewline\cline{3-3}
  & & Easy change if there are a new classes of signs &  \tabularnewline
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using the `makecell` package, one can have less typing. If the 1st column is entirely for row numbers, you also can use `listliketab` so that the rows can be cross-referenced:

```
        \documentclass{article}

        \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
        \usepackage{array}
        \usepackage{enumitem}
        \usepackage{makecell}
        \usepackage{listliketab}
        \usepackage[textwidth = 16cm, nomarginpar, showframe]{geometry}

        \begin{document}
          \begin{table}[!htbp]
        \centering
        \caption{Comparison of all discussed Classifiers}
        \storestyleof{enumerate}
        \begin{listliketab}
        \newcounter{rowenum}\setcounter{rowenum}{2}
        \newcommand{\nextrow}{\refstepcounter{rowenum}\therowenum.}
          \begin{tabular}{|L p{3cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|>{\raggedright}p{5cm}|}
         \hline
        \nextrow\label{tm} & Template Matching (TM) & \makecell*[c{p{5cm}}]{Computed very simple and Need matching the template over
         the image\medskip\\Easy change if there are a new classes of signs} & Rotation and Scaling variant \tabularnewline
         \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \end{listliketab}
        \end{table}
        As one can see in row \ref{tm}, […]
        \end{document}
```

[image]